# Outlook conditional formatting for number of attendees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conditional-formatting, calendar

How to colour code one-to-one meetings in the Outlook calendar?

I can't find a field in the conditional formatting list of fields that is "number of attendees".

Ideally the rule should be if a meeting is only between the organiser and one attendee then it's a one-to-one meeting and should be coloured "pink".

[image]

Comment: As i know, there's no such option in Conditional formatting for the one-to-one meeting as you mentioned.

Comment: Are you creating these meetings?

Comment: While I don't know how this would work, Outlook does support Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), a seriously capable programming language disguised as a macro language. I would wager than an Outlook macro could probably handle this, and handle it pretty easily. If you're in O365 in a business environment, it is possible that PowerAutomate might be another option, and one that will likely be better supported AND be functional in Outlook Online.

Comment: @spikey_richie, for some yes, but there could be ones where I am not the organiser.